# SwiftUIの画面遷移でTextをタップしても遷移が行われない

Tags: swift, swiftui

SwiftUIで画面遷移のテストをしているのですが、`NavigationLink`を使って遷移しようとしても、**1回目のTextのタップではうまく画面が遷移できますが2回目以降は無反応になってしまいます。**

[ContentView.swift]

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                NavigationLink(destination: SubView()){
                    Text("GO!!!")
                }

            } .navigationBarTitle("Home")
        }
    }
}



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[SubView.swift]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SubView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("this is subview").font(.title).fontWeight(.bold).frame(width: 400, height: 100).border(Color.orange, width:4)
    }
}

struct SubView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SubView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

お使いのXcodeのバージョンは11.3ではないでしょうか？
どうやらこのバージョンはシミュレーターにバグがあるようで、この現象が発生します。
おそらく実機で動かすとうまく動くかと思います。
残念ながら、最近リリースされた11.3.1でもこのバグは治っていませんでした。
仕方がないので私は未だに11.2.1を使っています。